# What's the best practice for defining types of variables without an initial value in typescript?

Tags: typescript, types, interface, initialization

In my current project, which uses React with typescript, I see that many times my colleagues use something like:

```
interface myObjectInterface{
   property: string | null
}
```

They do this because initially, the variable has no value, and only will have once the user interacts with the program. However, I've found that this creates problems down the road, and I think that if it doesn’t have an initial value, it should be initialized as an empty string (in case of strings) or zero (for number), or 'as ParticularInterface' (for objects), etc. Anyway, is there a best practice/standard for doing it? It would be really helpful if there’s some article where this is explained in detail.

Comment: `{property?: string}`

Comment: Don't think you meant it that way but your syntax is wrong, it's either `type MyObjectInterface = { ... }` or `interface MyObjectInterface { ... }` and `string | null` with a single `|`. What your definition means is there has to be a property named `property` but it can either be `null` or a `string`. `property?: string` on the other hand means you don't need to have that property but if it exists it needs to be a `string` and can't be `null`. Depends on what you want. Empty strings are worse because now you have another case of invalid. `property?: string` is most of the time the best IMO.

Comment: @zapl you're right, I just edited it. Sometimes, I do need the property to exist, so `property?: string` is not a solution.

Comment: What do you mean you *sometimes* need the property to exist?  Can you show, with a [mre], what goes wrong with `{property?: string}`?  If not, then this question is either not detailed enough or opinion-based and might be closed.

Comment: if you have default values that make sense, why not. But if they are only there because code fails to do null checks then fix that code. Empty strings or 0s sound more like the latter to me. In either of the other cases an `if (obj.property != null)` will ensure there's a usable value that isn't a pointless default that only signals "it's not a real value". There's also syntax like `obj.property ?? 0` which evaluates to a default of 0 if there's nothing in `obj`. And turn on `strictNullChecks` in tsconfig to see where things might be null

Comment: @zapl there are some null checks that the code shouldn't do. Consider something like `interface User { id?: string; name: string; }` - users always have a name, however, they get an ID once they are created. So *before creation* you'd have `{ name: "Fred" }` while *after creation* that becomes `{ id: "42", name: "Fred" }`. Now consider the signature `loadUser(id: string): User` it would be *logically* wrong to have to do a nullish-check. The user is already created, it *must* have an ID. Mandating nullish-checks for this situation is 1. useless 2. distracting. 3. doesn't match the data.

Comment: @VLAZ wasn't trying to say you have to null check everything. But in your example it also would not make sense to define it `id: string | null` and definitely not `id: string` and then using `""` as default. It would make sense to do `create(user: Omit<User, 'id'>)` and make the `id` mandatory to have "it must have an id" enforced by the type for everything that comes out of the db.

Comment: @zapl precisely. There are situations where having something nullable or optional is not a correct representation of the data. Essentially, there are two types to consider: `interface JustCreatedUser { name: string; }` and `interface UserFromDb { id: string; name: string; }` which more properly correspond to what is or isn't valid. Data can be a lot more complex, of course, the object can have multiple field with only some of them valid in situation. E.g., a verified user, then a a full user (with payment details). There is room for more expressive types than just nullable and optional.